# Absolutely continuity in variation of constant formula

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces, operator-theory

We are talking here about the initial value problem on some Hilbert space $H$
$$y'(t)=Ay(t)+f(t), \\ y(0)=y_0 \in D(A).$$(Problem 1.13 in the reference)

Then $y(t)=e^{At}y_0 + \int_0^t e^{A(t-s)}f(s) ds$ (in the reference called the mild solution) is a continuous function 1.13. for $A$ the generator of a $C_0$ group and $f \in L^1$.

Now, if $A$ is additionally assumed to be self-adjoint and dissipative ($\langle Ax,x \rangle \le 0$ for all $x \in D(A)$) and $f \in L^2,$ then the following reference claims that $y$ is even absolutely continuous. 
[click me to see the statement in Mathematical Methods in Optimization of Differential Systems on p. 174](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCHo8.jpg) 
But unfortunately, no proof is given. 
Does anybody know how to show this or know a reference where the proof is given?

Comment: No references given.

Comment: Please add to your question the assumptions made on $y_0$.  This seems to be an infinite-dimensional analog of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carathéodory%27s_existence_theorem

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee it is in the operator domain, thanks. But I do not really see how your quoted theorem relates to the question here.

Comment: Let $H=\mathbb{R}^n$ and consider the ODE $y'(t) = A y(t) + f(t)$ where $f$ is measurable.  Then Carathéodory's extension thm implies that this ODE has an absolutely continuous solution, even though $f$ is not necessarily continuous.

Comment: Also, just see the [equivalent definition (3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Equivalent_definitions) of absolute continuity on Wikipedia.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine but this one does not apply to the equation stated, as it is not $y(t)=y(0)+ \int_0^t y'(s)ds$ but $y(t)=e^{At}y(0)+ \int_0^t g(t,s)ds$ which is somewhat different.

Comment: @Torpedo, rewriting slightly, you have $y(t) = e^{At} (y(0) + \int_0^t e^{-As} f(s) \, d{s})$. As long as $e^{-As} f(s)$ is in $L^1$ with respect to $s$, you are done. By your hypotheses, $f\in L^2$, but on any compact interval $L^2 \subset L^1$.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I am not sure I get the point. All I see is that $g(t):=y(0)+\int_0^t e^{-As}f(s) ds $ is a.c.. Now you apply the semigroup to it, why is the function you get then a.c., too?

Comment: @Torpedo, maybe I'm missing something. $e^{At}$ is smooth in $t$, so (smooth) x (absolutely continuous) = (absolutely continuous). No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a bit on the comments made, let $P_t = \exp(A t)$ and write the Duhamel formula as: 
\begin{align*}
y(t) &= y_0 + (P_t - I) y_0 + \int_0^t P_{t-s} f(s) ds \\
&= y_0 + \int_0^t g(s) ds
\end{align*}
where we have introduced $g: \mathbb{R}_+ \to H$ defined as: 
$$
g(s) = P_s A y_0 + P_{t-s} f(s)
$$
To show that $g(\cdot)$ is integrable, 
\begin{align*}
\int_0^t \| g(s) \| ds &\le \int_0^t \left( \| P_s A y_0 \| + \| P_{t-s} f(s) \| \right) ds \\
&\le \| A y_0 \| \int_0^t \| P_s \|_{L(H)}  ds + \int_0^t \| P_{t-s} \|_{L(H)} \| f(s) \| ds  \\
\end{align*}
where we used the triangle inequality and basic properties of the operator norm.  To complete this bound, use the facts that (i) $\| P_t \|_{L(H)} \le 1$; (ii) $y_0 \in D(A)$; and (iii) $f$ is integrable.  Afterwards, invoke Khavkine's comment on the equivalent condition for absolute continuity.

Comment: sorry for asking again, but I looked first at this only on my cell-phone and now I noticed that I do not see why you needed all this: We have $\int_0^t ||P_sA y_0 ||+ ||P_{t-s} f(s)||ds$. What prevents us from estimating this like $||P_sA y_0 || \le ||P_s || \ ||Ay_0|| \le M e^{\omega t} ||Ay_0||$ by the growth condition for semigroups and $||P_{t-s} f(s)|| \le ||P_{t-s}|| \ ||f(s)|| \le M e^{\omega (t-s)} ||f(s)|| \le M e^{\omega t} ||f(s)||.$ Now, it would be sufficient to have $||f( \cdot)|| \in L^1$, right?

Comment: I would be very grateful to you if you could help me why you did it that way.

Comment: Is $\| f(s) \|$ uniformly bounded by a constant for all $s \in [0,t]$?  I don't see that anywhere in the given assumptions.

Comment: Where did I use this?

Comment: Here: $\| P_{t-s} f(s) \| \le \| P_{t-s} \|_{\mathcal{L}(H)} \| f(s) \|$.  (Note that I added the subscript to distinguish the operator from vector norms.)  Is this true for all $s \in [0,t]$?  If so, then I will edit my answer.

Comment: Well for evey $t \ge s \ge 0$ we have $P_{t-s} \in L(H)$ and for almost every $s \in [0,t]$ we have $f(s) \in H$. Hence for almost every $s$ and every $t$ satisfying  $t \ge s \ge 0$ we have $||P_{t-s} f(s)|| \le ||P_{t-s}||_{L(H)} || f(s)||$. I am sorry, I seem to be completely blind at the moment. What do you think can go wrong here?

Comment: Ok.  I edited my answer based on your feedback.